# Attempting to host a .net web application on Apache Mono

Tags: asp.net, linux, web-applications, mono

My group has been using BugTracker.NET (http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) hosted on an Windows server running IIS.  We need to relocate it to an intranet site supported on OpenSUSE running Apache.

I unfortunately do not have root on this machine. I've been able to work with the administrator and get the actual web server process running, have some access to some of the config files and sudo ability to restart the web server, but so far no access to view the log files (which is a pain).

I can run a simple web page on the server, and it indicates that Mono module is installed (Mono Version: 2.0.50727.42; ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.42).  The installation for bugtracker.net is basically to run

```
    where BTNET = name of instance and CD = current directory

    C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add app 
    /site.name: "Web Name" /path:/%BTNET% /physicalPath:"%CD%\www"
```

What's the equivalent to adding an application like this under Apache/mono?  Specifying the physical path, etc.?  Any suggestions on how to install this application? Because it is a third-party app with a number of custom configurations done on it, my preference is just to copy the application as is over to the new Linux server, but that's not working as it's not installed.  There are no installation functions within this app for installing on anything other than Windows IIS.

I've gone through a number of examples and documentation and not found anything that provides this information.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do would be to quickly test if your application works at least basically under mono.

I guess your Bugtracker app is provided as an archive (.zip or other)?

Unpack it on your Linux box in any location, then 'cd' to the root directory of this app and start the Mono light appserver:

```
xsp4 --port 8080
```

Then you should see if something happens.

Later, you should follow [this official tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) to configure Apache and define your app as a Mono/Asp.Net application

Comment: Thanks for the response. From my reading of other installation notes and documentation, I didn't think you needed to install xsp4 -- my intention was to run this using Apache with the mod-mono module added.  Found /usr/lib/xsp/test on the server, not sure if it's actually active or not.  Back to the drawing board.  I'll follow the tutorial you provided and see if that helps.

Comment: What is your mono version? (mono -V) Maybe you have just xsp2. Or maybe a package is missing (either mono-tools or mono-web, I don't remember). But sure, you don't need xsp, it's just a simple application&web server that allows to test some code very quickly.

Comment: More information has been revealed after a lot of digging about.  I am on Mono 2.0.1, and I do have xsp4 running after all.  I was able to follow the tutorial and get the examples running on the web server so .aspx pages are getting served up.  Now it appears there's another issue.

Comment: Seems that the bug tracker application has a number of hard-coded backslash paths in it that are causing issues. I've modified everything in any config file I can locate, but still finding some in the application code.  Short of heavy editing and rebuilding the app from code, gotten myself stuck here again.  I am going to try to track down the original author of the software, but wanted to check here for any other information on this particular 'issue' that I'm sure is frequently found when porting a windows .net app to run on unix.  Any ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: AHA! should have known there'd be an option for this.  MonoSetEnv MONO_IOMAP=all in my config and now I've moved to a different error. Not working yet, but different.

Comment: Mono 2.0.1 is really too old. I strongly advise you to upgrade so 2.10.x series before investigating further!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into that.